# Screen Resolution is not at 1920x1080 During Boot and First Lockscreen but fixes after login on my Ubuntu guess OS

Tags: display-resolution, vmware

I have been experiencing this issue ever since I've been using it in VMware. I confirmed that I installed open-vm-tools and open-vm-tools-desktop by running

```
$ systemctl status vimtoolsd
```

I even tried to change some settings in /etc/default/grub but no luck.

I just can get full res at boot

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS